# How mmap() works when used on an executable?

Tags: linux, operating-system, mmap, virtual-address-space, page-tables

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

- There are two files: `file1.c` and `file2.c`
- They are compiled into `exec1` and `exec2` respectively. `file2.c` makes use of functions from a static library.

`exec1` maps `exec2` into it's virtual address space using `mmap`. The following lines are from the `file1.c`:

```
#define MAX_SIZE_BYTES 4000000
fd = open(exec2_path, O_RDONLY);
addr = mmap(NULL, MAX_SIZE_BYTES, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

The following series of events happen:

1. `exec1` is executed.
2. `exec1` mmaps `exec2` to its virtual address space (what exactly happens here?)
3. `exec2` is executed (at this stage, `exec1` keeps running in the  background. What exactly happens now?)

PS: I intend to know what happens when `exec2` is on the disk and it is `mmap`ed by `exec1`? How does the virtual address space and the page tables corresponding to `exec1` change?
Next, when `exec2` is actually executed, it is brought to main memory. How things change? Where in memory are the static library functions that are used in `file2.c`? I do not have a clear idea of the process. Can anyone shed light on this topic?

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to do with this code. It looks like you are trying to a memory mapping of an executable file then discarding the address where you mapped it to.

Comment: I do not understand how I am discarding the address?

Comment: mmap(), in most of its settings, returns the address of the mapping.

Comment: I won't be discarding it. I will need that address. I corrected the code.

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to make the executable. On every system I have seen MAP_EXECUTABLE is reserved and does nothing. Check on your system.

Comment: why do you think `exec2` is executed? If you execute it separately, why do you think it's relevant here?

Comment: I am explicitly executing `exec2`. I think that after I seperately execute `exec2` (note that `exec1` still runs in the background), the page table entries of `exec1` change in some way. So, I mentioned it. But I do not have an idea of how and what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are going from a logical perspective. By that I mean that I simplifying file system issues that occur on some eunuchs systems.

Your mmap call is effectively creating a new page file, where exec2_path specifies that page file. You are setting up read only pages using this file with addr pointing to the start of the page range. If you start accessing the memory specified by addr, it will trigger page faults that will load data from the file exec2_path.

Because you only have read access to exec2_path file, running it as well has no effect on the executable doing the mapping.

mmap has two uses I can think of off the top of my head. Read only memmaps are often the most efficient way to read large files that you have to work with in memory, for example decoding images.

Read/write memmaps can be used (in conjunction with locking mechanisms) to exchange data among processes.

Comment: "If you start accessing the memory specified by addr, it will trigger page faults that will load data from the file exec2_path". If I access the memory specified by addr after `exec2` starts executing, it will not give me a page fault (in `exec1`), since the executable `exec2` is in RAM. Am I right?

Comment: In most systems (not, for example, embedded) an executable is not a map of how it exists in memory. An executable is a set of instructions that describe how the image is to be created in memory. Some parts of the executable are often memory mapped (executable code, read-only data). So your executable is not likely to be loaded into memory in exec1.

Comment: The `exec1` mmaps to `exec2` executable (considering `exec2` executable is different from `exec2` process). And from my limited understanding, I think that the text segment of the `exec2` process contains the `exec2` executable file (set of instructions that describe how the image is to be created in memory). Please correct me if I am wrong.